# $G$ non abelian, order $p^3$ ($p$ prime). Suppose that the center is $p^2$, prove that $\exists\ x$ outside of the center, of order p

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a non abelian group of order $p^3$, with $p$ prime.

I'm proving that $Z(G)$ (its center) is of order $p$. I already know how to do it by saying that its order can't be $p^3$, nor 1, and if it's $p^2$ then $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then G is abelian, Abs!

But I've been reading another way of proving it and the author supposes that $|Z(G)|=p^2$. Then, she says: **"$\exists\ x$ outside the center of $G$, of order $p$."** Could someone give me a hint? Thanks!

Comment: p is prime number?

Comment: Yes, I'll clarify that. Thanks

Comment: I doubt that you'll find a proof for the existence of an element of order $p$ outside the center **without** using that $\langle x, Y\rangle$ is abelian for $x\in G$ and $Y$ a subset of the center (which proves your goal directly as you already know).

Answer (score 2):

Take an element $a$ outside the center $Z(G)$. This is possible as the group is supposed to be non abelian. The order of $a$ divides $p^3$. If the order of $a$ is $p$ you're done. If it is $p^2$ then $a^p$ is of order $p$.

Comment: Oh god. Thanks!

Comment: But if the order of $a$ is $p^2$, then $a^p \in Z(G)$. (cc @SeñorBilly)

Comment: If $a^p \in Z(G)$ then you can prove that $a \in Z(G)$, maybe?

Comment: @SeñorBilly,it is not true.consider Klein group. and p=2.

Comment: Isn't $K$= the Klein group abelian? $Z(K)=K$

Comment: Ooops... Sorry for writing so big mistakes!

Answer (score 1):

For every $a \in G \setminus Z(G)$, we have $a^p \in Z(G)$, since $(G : Z(G)) = p$ by assumption.

If we already have $a^p = 1$ for the picked $a\in G\setminus Z(G)$, we're done, so let's suppose $a^p \neq 1$. The order of $a$ can then not be $p^3$, for that would mean $G$ is cyclic, hence abelian. Thus the order of $a$ must be $p^2$. If $Z(G)$ is cyclic, say generated by $g$, then $a^p = g^{kp}$, and $a\cdot g^{-k} \in G\setminus Z(G)$ with $(a\cdot g^{-k})^p = a^p\cdot g^{-kp} = 1$, so then we're done.

It remains to consider the case where $Z(G) \cong C_p \times C_p$. Pick $b \in Z(G) \setminus \langle a^p\rangle$. Then $G =\langle a,b\rangle$, and since $b \in Z(G)$ it follows that $G \cong \langle a\rangle \times \langle b\rangle$ is abelian, contradicting the assumption.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still proving the last part you said, but a comment: if $Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $a^p = g^p$, because $g^p$ is the only element of order p. No $k$ is needed.

Comment: @SeñorBilly No, the order of $g^{kp}$ is $p$ for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant p-1$, we need the $k$.

Comment: Oh right! I got confused and thought of $2p$ instead of $p^2$. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
What are the possible orders of an element in a group of order $p^3$, and what would it mean for such an element not to exist?

Comment: (I already understood how to do it, but let's see your way): I've already thought that if such an element doesn't exist, then every element has order $p^2$...so the exponent of the group is $p^2$, but I don't think that is useful. If $x\ \in\ G \Rightarrow |<x>| = p^2$. Also, 2 cyclic groups have trivial intersection or they are the same, so G could be written as Z(G) union cyclic groups of order $p^2$. Maybe I could prove that G is abelian, reaching a contradiction?

Comment: If every element is of order p^2, take one such element, and raise it by power p.

Comment: See above, how do you know that $a^p$ isn't in the center? Also, I have a mistake in my comment....not nocessarily 2 cyclic groups of order $p^2$ have trivial intersection or they are the same, I think. That sure happens if the order is **prime**.